# How can I turn nodes that made in shader editor to script?

Tags: python, scripting, shaders, add-on

I want to make a button and when I press it, it will apply the material I made, that mean the nodes.

I try different way to type script but it wasn't work.

```
bpy.ops.node.add_node(type="ShaderNodeTexNoise")
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5668/add-nodes-to-material-with-python  My recommendation is to test things out in the the python console.   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160042/principled-bsdf-via-python-api

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/200547/how-to-add-node-in-the-center-of-the-shader-editor-with-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding nodes to a material is best done using *low-level* functions. I'd suggest use [`Nodes.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Nodes.html#bpy.types.Nodes.new) instead of [`bpy.ops.node.add_node()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.node.html?highlight=add_node#bpy.ops.node.add_node). The `add_node()` operator is more for direct user interaction, and requires the correct context to run.

How to create a new node via material *data-block*, assuming a material name of "Material":

```
bpy.data.materials["Material"].node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexNoise")
```

Better practice is using pythons [`get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method to basically perform a search for the material in the first place and (avoids potential [index errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098643/indexerror-list-index-out-of-range-and-python)):

```
import bpy

mat = bpy.data.materials.get("Material")
if mat:
    mat.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexNoise")
```

Related:

- [Control Cycles material nodes and material properties in Python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23436/control-cycles-material-nodes-and-material-properties-in-python)
- [How to assign a new material to an object in the scene from Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23433/how-to-assign-a-new-material-to-an-object-in-the-scene-from-python)

Comment: Disagree on "best done via bpy.data", depends on the situation, you can also get the node tree reference from the editor or any object. Recommend use `get()` on the material data block (to avoid our famous index error) and ideally use the active object and its active material in *context*: `bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeTexNoise")`, can be easily incorporated into an operator as well (might be part of the question, not sure).

Comment: Re the question.. an option would be to  add a panel to node editor and put  operator button there, where there is `context.active_node` etc ....  suggest requesting  clarity re what the OP means by _apply the node to material_   linked and settings too?  @brockmann can you recall a node to script addon?

Comment: I mean turning nodes to script. I don't mean to use it in shader editor. I would like to add a button that apply the nodes when I press it

Comment: @BNFilms [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/214748/edit) your question to clarify.  Including where you want the button.  It really is not clear from question in its current form.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly you want to turn your material into its equivalent python nodes. Arguably this is a bit too involved for a single SE question because there are a lot of use cases. Thankfully I tackled this some months ago for a personal project so I can share what I worked on.

You'll need to learn [how to use a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409).

How to use :

Select your object, select the material you want to copy, run the script. The material code will be added in a new text block.

[image]

```
"""
This scripts "serializes" the active material of the currently selected object
And creates a script readable by the Blender API to recreate said Material.
As any Blender script, it is free to use in any way shape or form.
V 1.1 - 20.10.23
Fixed NodeSocketVirtual error
"""

import bpy

from bpy.types import (
    NodeSocketShader,
    NodeSocketVirtual,
    NodeSocketVector,
    NodeSocketVectorDirection,
    NodeSocketVectorXYZ,
    NodeSocketVectorTranslation,
    NodeSocketVectorEuler,
    NodeSocketColor,

    NodeReroute,

    Object,
    Image,
    ImageUser,
    Text,
    ParticleSystem,
    CurveMapping,
    ColorRamp,

    ShaderNodeTree,
)

from mathutils import Vector, Color


ERROR = "~ ERROR ~"

def get_link_statement(link):
    """
    Build the statement to re-create given link
    """
    return f"""\
links.new({link.from_node.path_from_id()}.outputs[{get_socket_index(link.from_socket)}]\
, {link.to_node.path_from_id()}.inputs[{get_socket_index(link.to_socket)}])\
    """


def value_from_socket(socket):
    """
    Returns the evaluated value of a node socket's default value
    """
    # A Shader socket (green dot) doesn't have a default value :
    if isinstance(socket, (NodeSocketShader, NodeSocketVirtual)):
        return ERROR
    elif isinstance(socket, (
            NodeSocketVector,
            NodeSocketVectorXYZ,
            NodeSocketVectorTranslation,
            NodeSocketVectorEuler,
            NodeSocketVectorDirection)):
        return f"{[socket.default_value[i] for i in range(3)]}"
    elif isinstance(socket, NodeSocketColor):
        return f"{[socket.default_value[i] for i in range(4)]}"
    else:
        return socket.default_value.__str__()


class NodeCreator:
    """
    Helper class to programmatically recreate the passed node
    """
    # These props are internal or read-only
    # and aren't useful in the serialization.
    default_props = (
        "dimensions",
        "draw_buttons",
        "draw_buttons_ext",
        "input_template",
        "inputs",
        "internal_links",
        "isAnimationNode",
        "is_registered_node_type",
        "output_template",
        "outputs",
        "poll",
        "poll_instance",
        "rna_type",
        "socket_value_update",
        "type",
        "update",
        "viewLocation",

        "texture_mapping",
        "color_mapping",

        "filepath",

        "cache_point_density",
        "calc_point_density",
        "calc_point_density_minmax",

        "interface",

        "height",
        "show_options",
        "show_preview",
        "show_texture",
        "width_hidden",
    )

    def __init__(self, node):
        """
        Initialize the node inputs and outputs,
        and the different fields' default values
        """
        self.node = node
        self.input_default_values = []
        self.output_default_values = []
        if not isinstance(node, NodeReroute):
            for _input in node.inputs:
                self.input_default_values.append(value_from_socket(_input))
            for output in node.outputs:
                self.output_default_values.append(value_from_socket(output))

        self.type = type(node).__name__
        self.properties = []  # Could use an ordered dict instead.
        for prop_name in dir(node):
            if prop_name.startswith("_") or prop_name.startswith("bl_"):
                continue
            if prop_name in NodeCreator.default_props:
                continue
            self.properties.append((prop_name, getattr(node, prop_name)))

    def statements(self):
        """
        Build the chain of statements to programmatically recreate the node
        """
        statements = []
        statements.append(f"new_node = nodes.new(type='{self.type}')")
        self.properties = sorted(self.properties, key=lambda p: p[0])
        for props_tuple in self.properties:
            prop, value = props_tuple
            if isinstance(value, ImageUser):
                statements.append(f"""\
img_text = new_node.{prop}
img_text.frame_current = {value.frame_current}
img_text.frame_duration = {value.frame_duration}
img_text.frame_offset = {value.frame_offset}
img_text.frame_start = {value.frame_start}
img_text.use_auto_refresh = {value.use_auto_refresh}
img_text.use_cyclic = {value.use_cyclic}
img_text.tile = {value.tile}\
                """)
                continue
            if isinstance(value, ParticleSystem):
                # /!\ Make sure this is executed after node.object statement
                statements.append(f"""\
if new_node.object:
    new_node.{prop} = new_node.object.particle_systems.get('{value.name}')
                """)
                continue
            if isinstance(value, CurveMapping):
                statements.append(f"""\
map = new_node.{prop}
map.clip_max_x = {value.clip_max_x}
map.clip_max_y = {value.clip_max_y}
map.clip_min_x = {value.clip_min_x}
map.clip_min_y = {value.clip_min_y}
map.tone = '{value.tone}'
map.use_clip = {value.use_clip}\
                """)
                # Remove the 2 starting default points and only these :
                for i, curve in enumerate(value.curves):
                    statements.append(f"map_c = map.curves[{i}]")
                    for point in curve.points:
                        statements.append(f"""\
map_c.points.new({point.location[0]}, {point.location[1]})""")
                    statements.append("""\
removed_start = removed_end = False
for i in range(len(map_c.points) - 1, -1, -1):
    p = map_c.points[i]
    if not removed_start and p.location[0] == map.clip_min_x and p.location[1] == map.clip_min_y:
        map_c.points.remove(p)
        removed_start = True
    if not removed_end and p.location[0] == 1 and p.location[1] == 1:
        map_c.points.remove(p)
        removed_end = True\
                    """)
                statements.append(f"map.update()")
                continue
            if isinstance(value, ColorRamp):
                statements.append(f"""\
cr = new_node.{prop}
cr.color_mode = '{value.color_mode}'
cr.hue_interpolation = '{value.hue_interpolation}'
cr.interpolation = '{value.interpolation}'\
                """)
                for stop in value.elements:
                    statements.append(f"""new_stop = cr.elements.new({stop.position})
new_stop.color = {[ch for ch in stop.color]}""")
                # Remove the 2 starting default stops and only these :
                statements.append("""\
removed_black = removed_white = False
for i in range(len(cr.elements) - 1, -1, -1):
    stop = cr.elements[i]
    if not removed_black and stop.position == 0 and all([stop.color[i] == (0, 0, 0, 1)[i] for i in range(4)]):
        cr.elements.remove(stop)
        removed_black = True
    if not removed_white and stop.position == 1 and all([stop.color[i] == (1, 1, 1, 1)[i] for i in range(4)]):
        cr.elements.remove(stop)
        removed_white = True\
                """)
                continue
            if isinstance(value, ShaderNodeTree):
                statements.append(f"""\
ng = bpy.data.node_groups.get('{value.name}')
if not ng:
    new_node.label = \"Missing Node Group : '{value.name}'\"
else:
    new_node.{prop} = ng\
                """)
                continue

            if prop in ("hide", "mute", "use_custom_color"):
                if value:
                    statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = {value}")
            elif prop == "text" and not value:
                continue
            elif prop in ("select", "shrink"):
                if not value:
                    statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = {value}")
            elif isinstance(value, str):
                if value:
                    statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = '{value}'")
            elif isinstance(value, Vector):
                if len(value) == 2:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.{prop} = ({value[0]}, {value[1]})")
                else:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.{prop} = ({value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]})")
            elif isinstance(value, Object):
                statements.append(
                    f"new_node.{prop} = bpy.data.objects.get('{value.name}')")
            elif isinstance(value, Image):
                statements.append(
                    f"new_node.{prop} = bpy.data.images.get('{value.name}')")
            elif isinstance(value, Text):
                if value:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.{prop} = bpy.data.texts.get('{value.name}')")
            elif prop == "parent":
                if value:
                    statements.append(f"""\
parent = nodes.get('{value.name}')
if parent:
    new_node.parent = parent
    while True:
        new_node.location += parent.location
        if parent.parent:
            parent = parent.parent
        else:
            break\
                    """)
            elif isinstance(value, Color):
                statements.append(
                    f"new_node.{prop} = ({value[0]}, {value[1]}, {value[2]})")
            else:
                statements.append(f"new_node.{prop} = {value}")
        for i, dv in enumerate(self.input_default_values):
            if dv == ERROR:
                continue
            statements.append(f"new_node.inputs[{i}].default_value = {dv}")

        for i, dv in enumerate(self.output_default_values):
            if dv == ERROR:
                continue
            statements.append(f"new_node.outputs[{i}].default_value = {dv}")

        if not isinstance(self.node, NodeReroute):
            for _input in self.node.inputs:
                if _input.hide:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.inputs[{get_socket_index(_input)}].hide = True")
            for output in self.node.outputs:
                if output.hide:
                    statements.append(
                        f"new_node.outputs[{get_socket_index(output)}].hide = True")
#        DEBUG Print node location as a label :
#        statements.append("new_node.label = str(new_node.location[0]).split('.')[0] + ', ' + str(new_node.location[1]).split('.')[0]")

        return statements


def serialize_material(mat):
    """
    Returns the ordered statements necessary to build the 
    Mateiral generation script
    """
    node_tree = mat.node_tree
    statements = [f"""\
import bpy
new_mat = bpy.data.materials.get('{mat.name}')
if not new_mat:
    new_mat = bpy.data.materials.new('{mat.name}')
    
new_mat.use_nodes = True
node_tree = new_mat.node_tree
nodes = node_tree.nodes
nodes.clear()
    
links = node_tree.links
links.clear()
    """]

    statements.append("# Nodes :\n")
    for node in node_tree.nodes:
        for st in NodeCreator(node).statements():
            statements.append(st)
        statements.append("")

    if node_tree.links:
        statements.append("# Links :\n")
        for link in node_tree.links:
            statements.append(get_link_statement(link))

    return statements


def write_material_to_text_block(obj):
    """
    Create or overwrite a text block with the same name as the material
    Which contains all the necessary statements to duplicate the material
    """
    if not obj or obj.type not in ('MESH', 'CURVE', 'VOLUME', 'SURFACE', 'FONT', 'META', 'GPENCIL'):
        return
    am = obj.active_material
    if not am or not am.use_nodes:
        return
    statements = serialize_material(am)

    text_block = bpy.data.texts.get(am.name)
    if text_block:
        text_block.clear()
    else:
        text_block = bpy.data.texts.new(am.name)

    for st in statements:
        text_block.write(st)
        text_block.write("\n")

    return text_block


def get_socket_index(socket):
    return socket.path_from_id().split(".")[-1].split("[")[-1][:-1]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    text_block = write_material_to_text_block(bpy.context.active_object)
```

The code is available there for grabbing
https://github.com/Gorgious56/Material2Script/blob/main/material_to_script.py

Comment: @brockmann Yeah figured I'd spend 5 minutes writing the answer rather than 10 mins trying to figure out the actual question :)

Comment: I can feel your fortune-telling skills.

Comment: @Gorgious very cool script. Coded something similar a few yrs back, as usual started neat, got spaghettified  and back-burnered. Pinching this instead.

Comment: @batFINGER Well a fair number of your answers helped me in the process so it's only fair ^^ thanks :) I'm thinking of updating it, a few nodes have been tweaked/added since (vectore rotate and attribute come to mind)

Comment: Finally UV'd, seems the OP is not willing to edit the q.

Comment: Hard to put a finger on the _"mind-reader_  factor.  _eg_  OP knows what they want and so should we, no edits required. @Gorgious thanks, consider asking a new Q re converting nodes to script. Given the accepted answer could prob re-title this one and shut it down as dupe.

Comment: Asked a new [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214911/whats-the-most-reliable-way-of-converting-a-material-into-reusable-code-blocks) @Gorgious, feel free to edit it and copy and paste your answer.