# Where is this “power” node?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I am trying to replicate a material with these nodes and they use a power node and it’s not on blender. i’m using 2.92

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Math Power Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/cycles/nodes/types/converter/math.html)**

[image]

This is the equivalent of the math function, eg

```
y = math.pow(x, 2)
```

for y equals x squared.  In the context of the node `x` is the value, 2 is the exponent.

See this answer re expanding the math node types in the UI https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197449/15543

Comment: Not only shows a small informative video but gives an explanation for how to use the node, I wish all answers were like this.

Answer (score 3):

That's a math node set to power. It's not a distinct node.