# How to get "Add Modifiers" panel as enum value?

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers

I need all modifiers list as my custom enum value,
i only know to write this by hand, here for example:

```
tp_mod = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
    name= "Slect by type",
    items=(
        ('SUBSURF', "Subdivision", ""),
        ('BEVEL', "Bevel", ""),
        ('MIRROR', "Mirror", ""),
        #AND SO ON..
        ),
    default='SUBSURF'
    )
```

is there anyway the best way to get all modifier as a enum value?
in other word how to make "Add Modifiers" panel as template for enum ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**All available via blenders rna.**

The `type` property of the modifier is an enum, can look up its definition via blenders "rna" system on the class, in this case `bpy.types.Modifier.bl_rna`

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Modifier

for item in Modifier.bl_rna.properties['type'].enum_items:
    print(item.identifier, item.name, item.description, item.icon)
```

output.

```
DATA_TRANSFER Data Transfer Transfer several types of data (vertex groups, UV maps, vertex colors, custom normals) from one mesh to another MOD_DATA_TRANSFER
MESH_CACHE Mesh Cache Deform the mesh using an external frame-by-frame vertex transform cache MOD_MESHDEFORM
MESH_SEQUENCE_CACHE Mesh Sequence Cache Deform the mesh or curve using an external mesh cache in Alembic format MOD_MESHDEFORM
NORMAL_EDIT Normal Edit Modify the direction of the surface normals MOD_NORMALEDIT
WEIGHTED_NORMAL Weighted Normal Modify the direction of the surface normals using a weighting method MOD_NORMALEDIT
UV_PROJECT UV Project Project the UV map coordinates from the negative Z axis of another object MOD_UVPROJECT
UV_WARP UV Warp Transform the UV map using the difference between two objects MOD_UVPROJECT
VERTEX_WEIGHT_EDIT Vertex Weight Edit Modify of the weights of a vertex group MOD_VERTEX_WEIGHT
VERTEX_WEIGHT_MIX Vertex Weight Mix Mix the weights of two vertex groups MOD_VERTEX_WEIGHT
VERTEX_WEIGHT_PROXIMITY Vertex Weight Proximity Set the vertex group weights based on the distance to another target object MOD_VERTEX_WEIGHT
ARRAY Array Create copies of the shape with offsets MOD_ARRAY
BEVEL Bevel Generate sloped corners by adding geometry to the mesh's edges or vertices MOD_BEVEL
BOOLEAN Boolean Use another shape to cut, combine or perform a difference operation MOD_BOOLEAN
BUILD Build Cause the faces of the mesh object to appear or disappear one after the other over time MOD_BUILD
DECIMATE Decimate Reduce the geometry density MOD_DECIM

etc, etc
```

Example of using math node type enum to create operator. [How to get custom menu items show up in the search bar?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/197439/how-to-get-custom-menu-items-show-up-in-the-search-bar/197449)